# How to validate JSON and Array types in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, validation, sqlalchemy

I have an `SQLAlchemy` model and two of the properties do not seem to be validated by `SQLAlchemy` nor do I get an error form the db which is counter intuitive and not what I would expect.

Specifically the `JSON` type and the `ARRAY(Text)` types do not fail when wrong types are passed to them. This is a dummy version of the model:

```
class Monitor(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'monitor'

    __table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint('user_id'),)

    _context = Column(ARRAY(Text), nullable=False)

    user_id = Column(UUID, ForeignKey('user.id'), index=True, nullable=False)
    _meta = Column(JSON, nullable=True, default={})
    enabled_at = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), nullable=True, default=now)
    disabled_at = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), nullable=True)
    user = relationship('User')
```

I am able to pass `integer`, `list`, `string`, `dict` whatever to the `_meta` `JSON` field. And no errors are raised. Also I can pass any iterable to the `Array(Text)` not just an array of strings.

Is there a way to enforce the validation of the declared types just with SQLAlchemy without writing my own validation logic?

Comment: Have you tried using a CheckConstraint to check the types ?

Comment: @MOSCODE No I haven't, how can I check for type in CheckConstraint? From what I see you can have logic in the check constrain but I don't know how to check for type.

Comment: All `integer`, `list`, `string` and `dict` types are valid JSON. As for the `ARRAY(Text)`, any specific reason you're using [`Text`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.Text) and not [`String`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.String) ? And what dialect are you using ?

Comment: I use Postgres. Yeah I kind of expected  JSON to be mapped to dict not to anything that can be turned into JSON, but ok.  For the text I expect the field to be quite long it is actually going to store a serialized python object.

Comment: @ljmc there is no way to have validation for Array[text] mapped to a list of strings and JSON to dictionary purely from SQLAlchemy?

Comment: @KZiovas, you can look into events for validation of specific column. See the example in https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/event.html#modifiers. I'll try to post a version for your case later today.

Answer (score 1):

SQLAlchemy does not perform any validation on the values it is given,  generally it passes values directly to the DB-API connector which might validate their type and will convert them as it needs.

The `JSON` type will accept anything a JSON encoder will (including but not limited to `None`, `int`, `list`, `string` or `dict`).

The `ARRAY(Text)` type will accept any iterable whose content can be turned into `str`.

Type validation must therefore be manual, staying in SQLAlchemy, that can be done by registering [`AttributeEvents.set`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.AttributeEvents.set) events, which check the type of the `set` values with [`isintance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance).

MRE:

```py
from sqlalchemy import ARRAY, JSON, Column, Integer, Text, create_engine, event
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()


class Monitor(Base):
    __tablename__ = "monitor"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    context = Column(ARRAY(Text))
    meta = Column(JSON, default={})


engine = create_engine(
    "postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/postgres",
    echo=True,
    future=True,
)

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)


@event.listens_for(Monitor.meta, "set")
def ensure_Monitor_meta_is_dict(target, value, oldvalue, initiator):
    if not isinstance(value, dict):
        raise TypeError(
            f"Monitor.meta accepts only dict values, not {type(value)}"
        )


@event.listens_for(Monitor.context, "set")
def ensure_Monitor_context_is_list_str(target, value, oldvalue, initiator):
    if not (
        isinstance(value, list) and all(isinstance(v, str) for v in value)
    ):
        raise TypeError(
            f"Monitor.context accepts only list[str] values, not {type(value)}"
        )


with Session(engine) as session:
    session.add(Monitor(context=["a", "b"], meta={1: 2}))
    session.flush()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Just one thing the K74809798 and t74809798 are not very helpful names for readers. Kind of weird choice given the example in the OP is much clearer. Also writing these validation method seems more work that just validating the values with a commonly used `@property` setter method? The point of the question was not how to validate the inputs in general, but if there is a configurable parameter within SQLAlchemy to get he validation out of the box.

Comment: @KZiovas, you're right, it's just a habit of mine to use the question ID in those, I'll edit to match your original names. As for the setter, yes that would be simpler, but SQLAlchemy wise, this is the only way I know to validate.

Comment: "SQLAlchemy uses the same duck typing philosophy as Python in general." - I think it's more correct to say that SQLA generally passes values directly to the DB-API connector, and let's the connector perform any type validation (or not).

Comment: @snakecharmerb you're correct, editing now.